# How to pass time dimension to postgis DB layer WHERE clause in Geoserver?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, query, time

I have successfully configured a layer with time dimension that is backed by an SQL query to a PostGIS DB.
I can query it through WMS, but I just can't find a way to pass the start and end time to the query (`WHERE` clause), so that the DB is the one filtering by time and not Geoserver. (I'm assuming that is what is going on, since my query doesn't have a where clause and works fine ... albeit inefficiently.)
Is it possible to pass start/end to the layer query and, if so, how?

Update:

Ok, I turned on postgresql logging and what geoserver is doing is wrapping my sql view layer in something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( <my sql view query> )
as "vtable" WHERE  ('2012-01-18Z' >= "start"
AND "start" IS NOT NULL
AND '2013-01-18Z' <= "end"
AND "end" IS NOT NULL
```

I also analyzed the execution plan vs. the execution plan of a simple query with the same where clause, and the costs where exactly the same.

In my case though, I'm dealing with a function, not a simple query so I'm not sure what the impact is. This is more of a postgresql question now. I'll post my findings here.

Comment: Instead of assuming why not turn up debugging to GeoTools dev level and look in the log file at the SQL generated. I'm pretty sure that the time dimension does get turned into a WHERE clause with postgis, of course you could also check the code.

Comment: Turn on statement logging in PgSQL to see what SQL is being sent.